# How to integrate $\frac{1}{2e^x-3e^{-x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find $\int\frac{1}{2e^x-3e^{-x}}dx$ and am completely stuck as to how to start. I was thinking it had something to do with the hyperbolic sine, but that didn't work.

Comment: Consider a substitution $u=e^x$; you should be able to get the integral into easily-managed form.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator by $e^x$.

Comment: $ e^x \cdot e^x=e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$

Answer (score 2):

If you replace $x$ with $\log t$ you are left with:
$$\int\frac{dt}{2t^2-3} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\int\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} t-\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}t+\sqrt{3}}\right)\,dt$$
that is easy to solve.